# Why is Vue.js a tick behind? Why do I need jQuery to get the current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a select element

```
<select id="filter" v-model="filter" @change="changeFilter">
 <option value="all">All</option>
 <option value="one">One</option>
 <option value="two">Two</option>
 <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Then in my component I have

```
methods:{
   changeFilter(){
        var that = this
        console.log(that.filter)
        // this gives me the value from the last select
        //  If I then use Jquery 
        that.filter = window.jQuery('#filter').val()
        console.log(that.filter)
        // This gives the correct up to date value
   }
```

}

Why is it that I ahve to use Jquery to get the most recent value of this element?
I thought Vue.js was supposed to be reactive?  Why is it one tick behind then??  Why am I forced to use jQuery to get the currently chosen selection?  Seems super counter intuitive to do that?

Comment: They actually have a pretty good explanation here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue You can use `Vue.nextTick()` if there's a reason you need to do this in a handler rather than just reacting to data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is doing a two-way binding plus an event.  The event is fired at the same time as the model update, therefore the change hasn't posted yet.

You'd be better off using a watch here.

First, remove the event:

```
<select id="filter" v-model="filter">
 <option value="all">All</option>
 <option value="one">One</option>
 <option value="two">Two</option>
 <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Then put the watch in your Vue object:

```
watch: {
    filter: function (val) {
      // use val here
    }
}
```

More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just replicating your code but it was just totally working fine.

Check the code below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   filter: 'all'
  },
  methods: {
   changeFilter: function() {
     alert(this.filter)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="filter" @change="changeFilter">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```